# Mi programa se queda escuchando y no avanza, no me muestra un error ni nada

Tags: python, python-3.x, vscode

Estoy tratando de probar la librería Speech Recognition de Python para el reconocimiento de voz y pasar a texto, sin embargo, cuando ejecuto el programa, el cursor permanece parpadeando y no avanza, no salen errores, tengo que presionar Ctrl + C para interrumpirlo.

Este es mi código, es solo un ejemplo

```
import speech_recognition as sr

   r = sr.Recognizer() 
   mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=0)
   with mic as source:
       print('Di algo: ')
       audio = r.listen(source)

       try:
          text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="es-EC")
          print('Tu dijiste:', text)
       except:
          print('No puedo escucharte')
```

Pero no hace nada y ni siquiera me da un error o devuelve el mensaje de excepción, se mantiene así

```
PS C:\Users\dell\Documents\Cuarentena\Pruebas de reconocimiento de voz> & C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe "c:/Users/dell/Documents/Cuarentena/Pruebas de reconocimiento de voz/prueba1.py"
Di algo:
|
```

Comment: Intentaste poner `text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="es-EC")` justo debajo de `audio = r.listen(source)`, y manejar los error con if y else? Creo que eso lo podría solucionar.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, y ya lo intenté sin éxito, el resultado es el mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Modifica:

```
audio = r.listen(source)
```

por

```
audio = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=3)
```

La función *listen* recibe 4 parámetros:

```
listen(
    source,
    timeout,
    phrase_time_limit,
    snowboy_configuration
)
```

El *source* es el origen del audio.
El *timeout* es el tiempo que trata de escuchar algo y luego se da por vencido, dando una exception `WaitTimeoutError`.
Y el que nos interesa, *phrase_time_limit*, es el tiempo que dura la frase a grabar: setea este número en la cantidad de segundos que grabará.